# Firebase Rules to let users see their own data, ERROR Listener at /jobs failed: permission_denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to figure out Firebase Rules that will allow my users to only see their data in their App.

Currently this is my Realtime Database File:

[image]

and this is my Firebase Set Rules:

```
 {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    },
    "jobs": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do i change the rules to be able to let users see their data that is relevant to their userid?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the user's UID as the key for their data in both `jobs` and `users`. In that case, you can ensure that each user can only read their own job and profile with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    },
    "jobs": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this is almost a literal copy of the sample in the [Firebase documentation on securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).

Comment: Sadly when using in my app with my Auth email i get this error: Listener at /jobs failed: permission_denied

Comment: Type read
Location 
Data null
Auth { "provider": "anonymous", "uid": "5HSJNaWoBFbU8nPSy3zND0gH6n92" }
Admin false

Comment: Please update your question to include the minimal code that produces that error, and the error message itself.

Comment: I have updated the question, however this answer does not work as still keep getting error messages when attempting accessing data

Comment: Your question still doesn't show any **code** that raises the error. But from the error message it is clear that you're reading the entire `/jobs` node, which these rules don't give allow (nor are they supposed to). I think you might be thinking that rules can be used to filter data, which they can't. For more on this, see the section [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) in the documentation, and [questions about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters) here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, will i have to "filter" my data within my xcode then?

Comment: Your question was "How do i change the rules to be able to let users see their data that is relevant to their userid?", which is done with the above rules. But that also requires that your code only tries to read the user's own node under `/users` and `/jobs`, so `/users/theiruid` and `/jobs/theiruid`.

Comment: Okay, so looking at my code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922028/firebase-realtime-database-rules-error-listener-at-jobs-failed-permission-de
How do i change mt code to allow this, as it keeps erroring every time i attempt too`?