# Firebase Realtime Database and Xcode: To allow each user to read their own data NOT all the data

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have added this to my code:

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
ref = Database.database().reference().child(userID);
```

Thinking this would work and give me the results I needed, as my rules are right, however the app just comes up with a blank table instead of it filled in with the details. Which is really weird!

Firstly here are my firebase rules:

```
  {
  "rules": {
    "jobs": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my firebase database:

[FirebaseDatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzLxT.png)

Here is the Firebase Auth with the UID

[FirebaseAuth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfati.png)

Here is my code:

*ViewController for Login Page:*

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    static var isAlreadyLaunchedOnce = false

    @IBOutlet weak var txtemail: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtpass: UITextField!


    var isSignin:Bool = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
       }
    }


    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let email = txtemail.text, let passowrd = txtpass.text

        { Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: passowrd) { (user, error) in
                if user != nil {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goto", sender : self)
                }
                else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Username or Password Incorrect", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(okButton)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

*View controller for Logged in Page*

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoggedInViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var loginlbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var tbl: UITableView!

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var jobList = [JobModel]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let job = jobList[indexPath.row]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        let job: JobModel

        job = jobList[indexPath.row]

        cell.lblCol.text = job.collection
        cell.lblDel.text = job.delivery
       cell.lblShip.text = job.shipper
        cell.lblCon.text = job.consignee
       cell.lblEmai.text = job.email
       cell.lblRef.text = job.reference
       cell.lblFreight.text = job.freight
       cell.collected.text = job.collected
       cell.delivered.text = job.delievered

        return cell  }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return jobList.count
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
FirebaseApp.configure()     }


ref = Database.database().reference().child("jobs");

ref.observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in

if snapshot.childrenCount>0 {

self.jobList.removeAll()

for jobs in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
    let jobObject = jobs.value as? [String: AnyObject]
    let jobId = jobObject?["id"]
    let jobShipper = jobObject?["shipper"]
    let jobConsignee = jobObject?["consignee"]
    let jobEmail = jobObject?["email"]
    let jobReference = jobObject?["reference"]
    let jobFreight = jobObject?["freight"]
    let jobCollection = jobObject?["collection date"]
    let jobDelivery = jobObject?["delivery date"]
    let jobPod = jobObject?["pod"]
    let jobCollected = jobObject?["collected"]
    let jobDelivered = jobObject?["delivered"]

    let job = JobModel(id: jobId as! String?,
            shipper: jobShipper as! String?,
            consignee: jobConsignee as! String?,
            email: jobEmail as! String?,
            reference: jobReference as! String?,
            freight: jobFreight as! String?,
            collection: jobCollection as! String?,
            delivery: jobDelivery as! String?,
            pod: jobPod as! String?,
            collected: jobCollected as! String?,
            delivered: jobDelivered as! String?)

            self.jobList.append(job)
}
            self.tbl.reloadData()
} } }


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    Auth.auth().currentUser != nil; do {

        self.loginlbl.text = "Hello " + (Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!


    }}



}
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstood. You have to create a json branch to store the jobs and users. Like `userID: { jobIDList }`. The `auth.uid` is the authed (usually userid), not the job id.

Comment: Again i am confused as in my database i do not have a job Id, i have created it the same as the UserId (auth.uid) to try and connect them up? Could you please example in a little more detail?

Comment: You mean "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
uid actually is userid? If it's right, I'm confused why **permission_denied** appears too

Comment: I think I see problem. You should listen to `jobs/uid` instead of just `jobs`.
The uid doesn't permission to read all of `jobs`, just can read `jobs/uid`

Comment: Like @tuledev said, a user only has permission to read/write their own data, not the entire jobs node. So you should either change the permissions to allow a user to read/write to the entire jobs node or change your code to only access the user's own data.

Comment: Hi Andre, that is exactly what i want to create so each user only has access to read/write their own data in the jobs node. Could you explain how to do this? In my code or in firebase rules?

Comment: Also @tuledev are you talking about my actual code?

Comment: This seems a follow up from your previous question, where I just explained that "rules are not filters". I recommend we keep the discussion in one place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829874/firebase-rules-to-let-users-see-their-own-data-error-listener-at-jobs-failed

Comment: If this is the ref you are working with `ref = Database.database().reference().child(userID);` and your rules are as shown in the question with this node being part of the rules `"jobs": {` then your ref and rules are not addressing the same node. You ref node is */root/uid* and your rules apply to */root/jobs/uid*

Comment: I have sorted my problem by adding this to my code:  if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            Database.database().reference().child("jobs").child(uid).observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in

Answer (score 0):

Your rules let you access to the children node of jobs. like `jobs/user_id_1`

So you have to listen to the child instead of the whole `jobs` node

`Database.database().reference().child("jobs");`

to

`Database.database().reference().child("jobs\loggedInUserID");`

Comment: Still getting error - Listener at /jobs failed: permission_denied

Comment: The error i am now getting in xcode: 
Invalid escape sequence in literal 
Missing argument for parameter 'byAppendingPath' in call
Insert 'byAppendingPath: <#String#>

Comment: I also added "jobs\\loggedInUserID" in swift, however still getting "Listener at /jobs\loggedInUserID failed: permission_denied"   annoyingly

Comment: well. `loggedInUserID` is a id of loggedIn user. It's a uid  like "vzWxCU..."

Comment: @mollywm try to get the uid of the user logged in.

Comment: Yes i can easily get the UID, i have tried to add this: let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid  then adding  ref = Database.database().reference().child("jobs").child(userID) however this does give me permission but gives me an empty table instead of the information i want

Comment: so the permission is solved?. try to print the result and anything.maybe you parse wrong thing.

Comment: Sadly no as given though its accessing the 'data' its not showing it or printing it Not sure why

Comment: do you access to the rightt uid. check the uid has data or not

Comment: Yes the UID has data and i think its the right one. Not sure why this hasnt worked to be honest

Comment: When putting them as true, I get to see the whole data not just my users that I've login with